# NLA Actions with Local Transformations

Tags: animation, nla-editor, actions

I have multiple objects in different locations that I have been animating with the NLA Editor.

These are the objects I'm referring to. They are supposed to be cartoonish birds.
[image: These are the objects I'm referring to. They are supposed to be cartoonish birds.]

This is the action I've been using to make them flap their wings.
[image: This is the action I've been using to make them flap their wings.]

I want to modify this "flap" action so that it causes the objects to move up and down as if the wings were propelling the birds upward before they fall down to their original height. How can I do this while keeping the objects in the same relative location? So far, I've only been able to animate their location globally, so I can modify the action, but it will put all of them in the exact same coordinates, which is not what I want. I want the action to affect the objects’ local location, not put them all in the same place.

Comment: please show some screenshots

Comment: You can add an empty as a parent and animate its location.

Comment: "You can add an empty as a parent and animate its location." You can. But is this the expected workflow? Is there no way to set keyframes in local space?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the Blending of the active action (or a strip on a higher track) to 'Combine'. This way the two locations will be added together instead of the top action overriding the lower one.

[image: Example of an action with the 'Combine' Blending mode]